# Amazon Connect is not recording calls to an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

### Synopsis

I set up a new Amazon Connect instance, and a Direct Inbound Dial (DID) phone number. I set up the phone number to point to the `Sample Recording Behavior` contact flow. To test it out, I called into the DID phone number, and pressed `1` to set up agent/customer recording. Then I chose the option to enter a queue, and used the Amazon Connect soft phone to answer the call from my web browser.

Amazon Connect automatically created an Amazon S3 Bucket, but the recording of the conversation was never created.

### Actual Result

- No recording was stored in Amazon S3 Bucket.
- S3 Bucket was empty.

### Expected Result

Amazon Connect stores a copy of the call recording, from both agent/customer sides, in the Amazon S3 Bucket that was created for the instance.

**Question**: How do I make Amazon Connect store call recordings into Amazon S3, if the default configuration does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon Connect instance configuration has a `Data Storage` section. Underneath `Data Storage`, there is a configuration section called `Call Recordings`. You can set a custom Amazon S3 Bucket in this section to capture call recordings. The IAM Service-Linked Role will automatically be configured with a custom in-line IAM policy that grants the necessary permissions to Amazon S3 APIs.

During my testing, in order for a call recording to be finalized and stored in the Amazon S3 Bucket, the connected agent **must** finalize the contact.

[image]